# Adding elements to a thread's vector and printing them - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

My goal is to start three unsynchronized threads and have them add a thousand elements each. These elements need to be stored in a set (I chose Vector) and then printed. For some reason I am not getting the elements to print. I've tried trouble shooting the print method and the method that creates the elements. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MyRun implements Runnable{
    int global = 0;
    //create sets
    static Vector t1v = new Vector();
    static Vector t2v = new Vector();
    static Vector t3v = new Vector();           
    public void run() {
        action1();
    }
    public void action1() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            global++;
            int x = global;
            String tName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if(tName == "t1") {
                t1v.addElement(x);
                System.out.println(t1v.elementAt(x));
            }
            if(tName == "t2") {
                t2v.addElement(x);
            }
            if(tName == "t3") {
                t3v.addElement(x);
            }           
            //System.out.println("thread: " + tName  + "counter is: " + global);
        }   
        }
    public static Vector gett1v() {
        return t1v;
    }

    public static Vector gett2v() {
        return t2v;
    }

    public static Vector gett3v() {
        return t3v;
    }

}

class ThreadTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create threads
        Runnable threadJob = new MyRun();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t1.setName("thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t2.setName("thread2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t3.setName("thread3");


        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        Vector th1v = MyRun.gett1v();
        Vector th2v = MyRun.gett2v();
        Vector th3v = MyRun.gett3v();
        //MyRun.printSets();
        for(int i=0; i < th1v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: " + th1v.elementAt(i));
        }

        for(int i=0; i < th2v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: " + th2v.elementAt(i));
        }


        for(int i=0; i < th3v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 3: " + th3v.elementAt(i));   
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: There a lot of issues, I'm afraid. You chose a deprecated, non-multithread-safe, class like `Vector` to holds the elements, on top of this you don't synchronise the consumer with the producers. Plus the non-atomic global. Ah, and the mismatching threads names (compared with object equality, that works in this case due to interning but may creep up a few developers) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to modify your code a bit.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyRun implements Runnable{
    AtomicInteger global = new AtomicInteger(0);
    //create sets
    static Vector t1v = new Vector();
    static Vector t2v = new Vector();
    static Vector t3v = new Vector();           
    public void run() {
        action1();
    }
    public void action1() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            global.incrementAndGet();
            int x = global.get();
            String tName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if(tName == "t1") {
                t1v.addElement(x);
            }
            if(tName == "t2") {
                t2v.addElement(x);
            }
            if(tName == "t3") {
                t3v.addElement(x);
            }           
            //System.out.println("thread: " + tName  + "counter is: " + global);
        }   
        }
    public static Vector gett1v() {
        return t1v;
    }

    public static Vector gett2v() {
        return t2v;
    }

    public static Vector gett3v() {
        return t3v;
    }

}

class ThreadTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create threads
        Runnable threadJob = new MyRun();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t1.setName("t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t2.setName("t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(threadJob);
        t3.setName("t3");


        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();

        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        Vector th1v = MyRun.gett1v();
        Vector th2v = MyRun.gett2v();
        Vector th3v = MyRun.gett3v();
        //MyRun.printSets();
        System.out.println(th1v.size()+" "+th2v.size()+" "+th3v.size());
        for(int i=0; i < th1v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: " + th1v.elementAt(i));
        }

        for(int i=0; i < th2v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: " + th2v.elementAt(i));
        }


        for(int i=0; i < th3v.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread 3: " + th3v.elementAt(i));   
    }
    }
}
```

Few things to Note :

- main thread is independent of t1 ,t2, t3  threads so if you want to
  get the result use join() or use FutureTask or
  ExecutorService.submit(Runnable r) . so main thread will wait for the
  all the three threads to complete and then execute the for loops.
  since main thread was not waiting , your were getting an empty output.
- Use Atomic types if their are multiple mutator threads , but there is only one mutator thread and multiple reader threads use a volatile keyword instead ,but using volatile keyword is expensive.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: The main thread needs to wait for the threads to complete -- that makes sense to me now. Thank you for helping me determine the error.

Comment: can you upvote and check the answer, if you find the answer is helpful !!